# Store data from the file into array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a file which contain these data :

```
6
1231234213 12
2312354234 23
3254132515 43
```

I want to store all these data into an array :

```
int main() {
    ifstream infile("data.txt");
    ofstream outfile("final.txt");
    int sn = 0;
        infile >> sn;
    int* arr;
    arr = new int[sn];
    for (int i = 0; i < sn; i++)
    {
        infile >> arr[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < sn; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

but I'm getting this instead of those data :

```
1231234213
12
2147483647
-842150451
-842150451
-842150451
```

Comment: Always test the stream state after an IO transaction. Error conditions that you spend time don't trapping  and handling generally waste orders of magnitude more time debugging.

Comment: note that 2312354234 is bigger than integer max value 2147483647 (0x7FFFFFFF)

Comment: Side note: -842150451 is a magic debug value. In hex it is CDCDCDCD, a pattern used to help you trap uninitialized heap-allocated values. When you see a nice repetition like this or a huge weird number, convert it to hex and see if it is more recognizable. [Here's a list of well-known debug values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Debug_values).

Comment: The output of 2147483647 is also a helpful number. It is 7FFFFFFF, signifying exactly what Gian is warning you of.

Comment: You could switch to use `int64_t` instead of int if your data requires 64 bit integers.

Comment: read as characters instead.

Answer (score 2):

When testing with an array of `long long int` your problem disappears:

```
int main() {
    std::ifstream infile("data.txt");
    int n = 0;
    
    infile >> n;

    long long int *arr = new long long int[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        infile >> arr[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        std::cout << arr[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1231234213
12
2312354234
23
3254132515
43
```

You might make things easier on yourself by using a `std::vector`.

```
int main() {
    std::ifstream infile("data.txt");
    int n = 0;
    
    infile >> n;

    std::vector<long long int> vec(n);

    for (auto &i : vec) {
        infile >> i;
    }

    for (auto i : vec) {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If we use just `int`, we can check if the read succeeded. How you choose to handle that error is up to you and the requirements of your program.

E.g.

```
    for (auto &i : vec) {
        if (infile >> i) continue;
        std::cerr << "A problem occurred." << std::endl;
        i = -2;
    }
```

Now output is:

```
A problem occurred.
A problem occurred.
A problem occurred.
A problem occurred.
1231234213
12
-2
-2
-2
-2
```

Comment: this solve the problem (for that input), but doesn't address the main problem in original code: not checking for error while reading from the stream. 
error will happen again, unhandled, for something such "AB" or "12345678901234567890" in input file